# how to return domain on onchange?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

What I need is once I select `patient_id`  only `nameLab` of `patient` when `patient` == `patient_id` appear

```py
class labinvoice (models.Model):
    _name = "lab.invoice"
    name = fields.Char(string='Invoice Reference',  default=lambda self: _('New'), store=True)
    patient_id = fields.Many2one(string='Patient',comodel_name='medical.patient',required=True, store=True )
    order_line = fields.One2many('lab.order.line', 'order_id', string='Order Lines', copy=True,  )  
    nameLab = fields.Many2one('medical.lab.patient',related='order_line.nameLab',string='name Lab', store=True)
    patient = fields.Many2one('medical.patient',related='order_line.patient',string='name Patient', store=True, readonly=True )
```

```py
class LabOrderLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'lab.order.line'
    _description = 'labs Order Line'
    name = fields.Text(string='Description', required=True)
    order_id = fields.Many2one('lab.invoice', string='Invoice Reference', required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)


    nameLab = fields.Many2one(
        string='Lab',
        comodel_name='medical.lab.patient',
        required=True,
        ondelete='cascade',
    )

    patient= fields.Many2one(
        'medical.patient',
        string='patient',
         related='nameLab.patient_id',
         readonly=True,
        required=True,
    )
```

```xml
                        <page string="Order Lines">
                            <field name="order_line" mode="tree,kanban" > 
                                <tree  editable="bottom" >

                                    <field name="nameLab"  />
                                    <field name="patient" /> 
                                    <field name="doctor_id"/>
                                     <field name="Test_Prix"/>
                                     <field name="test_type_id" />
                                     <field name="invoice_status"/>
                                     <field name="state" /> 
                                </tree>
```

I tried with onchange but in vain

```py
    @api.onchange('patient_id')
    def onchange_patient_id(self):
        if self.patient_id:
            self.order_line = False
            return {'domain':{'nameLab':[('nameLab.patient','=',self.patient_id.id)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a `domain` on the field definition in XML.

```
<field name="nameLab" domain="[('patient', '=', patient)]"/>
```

Comment: @SOS-Mona You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I can create entries no problem and they appear in the database. but I cannot however get the tree view to display any data at all. do you have an idea why?

Comment: @SOS-Mona You should ask that as a separate question since it is it is different than this domain question. Be sure to I Clyde bow you are creating entries and how you have your tree view set up.